# Get town/city name via geolocation in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

Is there a way to get the geolocation via a city or town name via google maps api?

I'm trying to get the geolocation of the towns of Puerto Rico, for example, I want to get the geolocation of `San Juan`, would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, right after asking this I found the documentation for it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro